# Custom Dropdown Editor Control in PropertyGrid is displayed in WHITE color

Tags: controls, custom-controls, propertygrid

Got a bit of a run with PropertyGrid control and now stumbled upon a curious problem.
I've got an Uint32 property in a class which is a bit mask.
So I decided to create a custom dropdown UserControl with 32 buttons to make Uint32 editable.
Here is the class (without button click handlers):

```
class MaskEditorControl : UserControl, IIntegerMaskControl
{
        public MaskEditorControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public UInt32 ModifyMask(IServiceProvider provider, UInt32 mask)
        {
            IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService = null;
            if (provider != null)
                editorService = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;

            if (editorService != null)
            {
                m_mask = mask;
                checkBox0.CheckState = (m_mask & (1 << 0)) == 0 ? CheckState.Unchecked : CheckState.Checked;
                checkBox1.CheckState = (m_mask & (1 << 1)) == 0 ? CheckState.Unchecked : CheckState.Checked;
                checkBox2.CheckState = (m_mask & (1 << 2)) == 0 ? CheckState.Unchecked : CheckState.Checked;
                editorService.DropDownControl(this);
            }

            return m_mask;
        }
        private UInt32 m_mask = 0;

}
```

ModifyMask(...) is the implemented function of IIntegerMaskControl interface which is being called from another class:

```
public interface IIntegerMaskControl
{
    UInt32 ModifyMask(IServiceProvider provider, UInt32 mask);
}

public class IntegerMaskEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public static IIntegerMaskControl control = null;

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        if (control == null)
            return "Error: IIntegerMaskControl not set!";

        return control.ModifyMask(provider, (UInt32)value);
    }
}
```

And here is the property itself:

```
    [System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute("Base")]
    [Editor(typeof(IntegerMaskEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public UInt32                                   renderMask { get; set; }
```

It works, but I got my control shown in White colors (including buttons) which just looks wrong. I cannot find out why. Here is the link to the screenshot: [that is how the control looks like in action](http://mad-god.webs.com/control.JPG).
Anyone have any ideas on why and how to avoid it? I could go with calling a Form but I'd rather stick with the dropdown.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property grid uses the [ViewBackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.viewbackcolor.aspx) property to display the drop down back color. I don't see any other property that allows to change the drop down back color.

However, the control shown in the drop down is parented to a control (a Form) that you can modify, with a code like this:

```
public partial class MaskEditorControl : UserControl, IIntegerMaskControl
{
    private Color _initialBackColor;

    public MaskEditorControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _initialBackColor = BackColor;
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        if (Parent != null)
        {
            Parent.BackColor = _initialBackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot up-vote that answer (not enough reputation), but it worked. Thanks! Is there a way to tell the control not to pick the Parent's back color? That would have been the best way.

Comment: I don't think so, the drop down holder form (the parent) uses the view color, I think it's by design so it looks better - from the property grid creator point of view :-).